# mysqli_fetch_array выдает пустую строку

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Здравствуйте.
Раньше, работая на старом **php**, использовал:

```
$rs = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($rs);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $row['login'];
}
```

Сейчас перешел на новую версию **php**, и приходится использовать **mysqli**
Как такую же операцию проделать на **mysqli**?

Пытался делать так:

```
$rs = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($rs);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    printf($row["login"]);
}
```

Ошибок не выводит. Просто выдает пустую строку

Comment: Почитайте документацию, у mysqli при запросе 2 параметра. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: А ошибок он не выводит скорее всего потому, что их вывод отключен. Смотрите лог ошибок.

Comment: В моем случае как нужно написать код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query` требует два аргумента, первый из которых - соединение с БД.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "example");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users");
//                     ^^^^^ вы пропустили
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_dump($row["login"]);
}
```